# JavaFX. Observable two-dimesional read-only observable collection of custom class

Tags: javafx, observable

My goal is a **model**, which will provide **two-dimensional read-only** observable collection of custom class called **Token**. Imagine it as rows of tokens.

1. row: [Token1, Token2, Token3, …]
2. row: [Token11, Token12, …]
3. …

I would like to know how correctly handle this events:

- added/removed whole row
- added/removed specific token on specific row -- I need to know index of 
  concerned row

Which data structure may I use to make returned observable collection read-only? `unmodifiableObservableList`?

---

*Code draft:*

```
public class Model {
   private ObservableList<ObservableList<Token>> tokens;

   public Model {
      // Some init data
      tokens = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
         final ObservableList<Token> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
         tokens.add(i, row);
         for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            row.add(new Token(i * 100 + j));
         }
      }
   }

   public ObservableList<ObservableList<Token>> getTokens() {
      return tokens;
   }
}

public class Processor {
   private Model model;

   public Processor() {
      model = new Model();

      model.getTokens().addListener(…) {…}
   }
}
```

Comment: If your observable is read-only, why would you need add and remove methods? For that matter, why does it have to be `Observable` at all?

Comment: You are right, it is not clearly writed. Inside `Model` class, there are changes of observable collection possible, but outside `Model` are forbidden -- the returned collection will be read only if someone call method `getTokens()`.